# Call other functions from a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
var Tset = function(){
     this.a = $('div').text("lorem ipsum ..").appendTo('#a1');
     $(this.a).mouseover(function(){
              this.setBackground('red');
     });  
     this.setBackground = function(_color){
        $(this.a).css({'background-color':'color'});
        }
}

var x = new Tset();
```

My Problem is that i cant call `this.setBackground` from the `mouseover` callback function. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Dont you want `css({'background-color': _color})`?

Comment: @OskarAlfons Just saw that you unaccepted my answer, i was just wondering what is wrong with the answer, a feed back would be really helpful for me to improve my answer. Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, inside the callback `this` refers to the element not the context of your instance. so try caching `this`.

```
var Tset = function () {
    var self = this; //<-- cache this to be used later
    this.a = $('div').text("lorem ipsum ..").appendTo('#a1');
    $(this.a).mouseover(function () {
        self.setBackground('red'); //invoke it with self
    });
    this.setBackground = function (_color) {
        $(this.a).css({
            'background-color': _color
        });
    }
}

var x = new Tset();
```

There are other techniques available similar to this, that are using Ecmascript5 [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) etc.

Using bound function:

```
 var Tset = function () {

     this.a = $('div').text("lorem ipsum ..").appendTo('#a1');
     $(this.a).mouseover((function () {
         this.setBackground('red'); //Now this will be your instanc's context
     }).bind(this)); //bind the context explicitly  
     this.setBackground = function (_color) {
         $(this.a).css({
             'background-color': _color
         });
     }
 }
```

*Except for the bound functions, caller determines the context inside the callback*

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FcVHA/)**

Answer (score 2):

Within jQuery event handlers, `this` is set to the element on which the event occurred.

However, in the parent function where you bind the callback, you can declare another variable to store that function's `this`, and refer to that variable in the callback.

Like so:

```
var Tset = function(){
    var that = this;// Declare another variable to store the parent function's "this" value.

     this.a = $('div').text("lorem ipsum ..").appendTo('#a1');
     $(this.a).mouseover(function(){
              that.setBackground('red');// And refer to that variable in your callback.
     });
```